# Classic thesis "Undefined control sequence. [....\relax }}{12}{figure.caption.8}]" error when generating list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents, classicthesis, undefined

I'm using the classic thesis template and I get the following errors on generation of the List of Figures:

```
/home/report/report.lof:13: Undefined control sequence. [...\relax }}{12}{figure.caption.8}]
/home/report/report.lof:13: Missing number, treated as zero. [...\relax }}{12}{figure.caption.8}]
```

At first I thought this was because I messed up a figure somewhere, but I commented out all of the figures in my report except one and the error still persists. The one figure still left is structured as follows:

```
\begin{figure*}[ht!]
    \centering
    \input{img/some_img.png}
    \caption{Caption.}
    \label{fig:some_img}
\end{figure*}
```

The file I'm using to generate the TOC and the accompanying list of figures is exactly the same as the one found here: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis/FrontBackmatter/Contents.tex .

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Per request, I've created a MWE at sharelatex: https://www.sharelatex.com/project/59e9faabf41d5451ffb89d63

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Try with `\includegraphics{./img/someimg.png}` and try to avoid special characters like `_` in file names. If this does not help, please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: Added minimal working example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the combination of the `subcaption` package with the `subfig` option of the  `classicthesis` package, which causes the `subfig` package to be loaded. These two packages are not compatible, I suggest to only use the `subcaption` package and remove the `subfig` option.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{graphicx} 

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[
            %subfig
            ]{classicthesis} 

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure*}[ht!]
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img/log.jpg}
    \caption{Test.}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This solved it, thanks! I'm wondering, how do you go about diagnosing these kinds of problems?

Comment: @user1870238 simply by constructing a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). Make a copy of your project remove everything that will not make the error go away. In the few remaining lines, the source of the problem is located.